# Identifying MySQL ID in a form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, identify

Using the following code:

```
<?php
print"<form name='delete' action="" method='POST'>
<input type='text' name='ID' value=".$info['ID'].">
<input type='submit' value='Delete Car' onclick='deleteRecord(); return false;'>
</form>";
?>
```

Is giving me the following error message, which in turn won't let me load the page:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in (etc)...
```

It is meant to get the ID of an MySQL record from user input.

What is wrong with that? I have another file where it works without any problems.

Comment: Please add more code, that error occurs when you miss a dot or a quote in php... Put the complete line that the error points

Comment: @AxelA.Grazx sorry. I edited the question with the full php code snippet. I actually copied it word for word from another page of mine I used somewhere else. The difference being that on that page it actually works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
<form name="delete" action="" method="POST">
    <!-- Use php echo instead of print -->
    <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $info['ID'] ?>">
    <!-- Try not to use inline javascript -->
    <button type="submit" onClick="deleteRecord(); return false"></button>
</form>
```

In `action=""` the quotes where messing with your php, so I recommend not to print html tags with php. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Look at `<form name='delete' action=""`. I think the problem is the double quotes. Change it to `<form name='delete' action=''` and see what happens.

Comment: That worked. I feel silly now for such a pitty mistake... I'll blame it on the lateness.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a missing PHP closing tag somewhere nearby? As in `?>`

Or just a syntax error somewhere in the file.